# Python change variable value in main file from tkinter checkbutton different file

Tags: python, tkinter, bots

i'm trying to make some autoclicker bot for a game and i have some question/problem.
i created a working bot for now and the next step is to create GUI which control different options of the bot.
i'm using Tkinter in a different file..
i created 2 checkbuttons in the window with configuration that the variables they control are from the Main file, with onvalue and off value
when i import the GUI file into the Main file i can't even make the bot start with my configured hotkeys...

That's pretty much the Main file:

```
import keyboard
import mouse
import time
from pyautogui import position, size
from PIL import ImageGrab
import AutoClicker

####### Variables For The App #######

UpgradeControl = False
LevelControl = False

#####################################

def main():
    def Upgrades():
        if Hero1.state == 1:
            Hero1.Press()

    def Levels():
        if int(time.time() * 100) % 60 == 0:
            mouse.move(NextLevelPos[0], NextLevelPos[1])
            mouse.click()
    AutoClicker.Window()
    scanScreen()
    InitializeColors()
    Hero1Pos = (int(ScreenSize[0] * Hero1ButtonRelativePos[0]), int(ScreenSize[1] * Hero1ButtonRelativePos[1]))
    Hero1 = Hero(Hero1Pos, 1)
    run = None
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('shift') and keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
            run = True
        while run:
            scanScreen()
            CheckHero(Hero1)
            mouse.move(MonsterPos[0], MonsterPos[1])
            mouse.click()
            if UpgradeControl:
                Upgrades()
            if LevelControl:
                Levels()
            if int(time.time() * 100) % 60 == 0:
                CollectCoins()
            if keyboard.is_pressed('shift') and keyboard.is_pressed('b'):
                run = False
            if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
                exit(1)
        if keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
            exit(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And that's the GUI File:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
import Main

def Window():
    AutoClicker = Tk()
    AutoClicker.title("Auto Clicker for Clicker Heroes")
    AutoClicker.geometry("500x280")

    AutoClicker.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    AutoClicker.columnconfigure(1, weight=3)
    AutoClicker.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    AutoClicker.rowconfigure(1, weight=3)

    menuBar = Menu(AutoClicker)
    FileMenu = Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0)
    FileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda: exit(1))
    menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=FileMenu)

    AboutMenu = Menu(AutoClicker, tearoff=0)
    AboutMenu.add_command(label="Contact")
    AboutMenu.add_command(label="About", command=lambda: aboutWindow())
    menuBar.add_cascade(label="About", menu=AboutMenu)

    AutoClicker.config(menu=menuBar)

    OptionLevel = Checkbutton(AutoClicker, text="Control levels", height=1, width=10, variable=Main.LevelControl, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
    OptionUpgrade = Checkbutton(AutoClicker, text="Control Upgrades", height=1, width=13, variable=Main.UpgradeControl, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)

    OptionLevel.place(relx=0.09, rely=0.35, anchor='w')
    OptionLevel['font'] = ("Lato", 14)
    OptionUpgrade.place(relx=0.091, rely=0.44, anchor='w')
    OptionUpgrade['font'] = ("Lato", 14)

    AutoClicker.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is weird... But here's how to work with global variables.   https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp

Comment: @MrkalvinBs its my first approach to an autoclicker so it could be weird, but how to work with global variables doesn't help me or answers my question